Postfix smtp problem
I have a postfix mail server with dovecot. If I send a  mail through Gmail smtp (relayhost) the mail is successfully received by the gmail.com server, but if I send mail form Gmail address to my postfix server the server can't receive the mail. Incoming mail does not appear in the log. The 25 port is opened.
Here is the  main.cf:
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

append_dot_mydomain = no

myhostname = domnain.xyz
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost, domnain.xyz

mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128

mailbox_size_limit = 5000000000
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
#smtpd_sasl_type = cyrus
#smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
#smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
#broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes

# Enable SASL authentication
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl/sasl_passwd
#smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination

smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/key_xyz.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/server.key
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/key_xyz.ca-bundle
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauthenticated_sender_login_mismatch


server distro/version?
